# SOLID stored procedures and functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, oop, design-patterns, stored-procedures

I want to start using stored procedures more in an application I am working with.  The application searches a dozen or so databases.  The application stores information in its own database.

I was thinking about offsetting business logic to stored procedures in specific databases.  Therefore if the logic is generic to all external databases then hold it in the application (.NET).  If the logic is specific to a database then create a stored procedure.

I am unsure how SOLID works with stored procedures and functions as there are no interfaces or abstractions.  The following post seems to suggest that you should try to consolidate queries: http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/building-solid-databases-interface.html.  For example, if a stored procedure has four SQL statements, then why not try to combine them into one SQL statement? Is this what the post is saying? Is this a SOLID approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking about offsetting business logic to stored procedures in
>   specific databases. Therefore if the logic is generic to all external
>   databases then hold it in the application (.NET). If the logic is
>   specific to a database then create a stored procedure.

This statement causes great concern in my mind.  When you say if the logic is specific to a database, to which I presume you mean one of the twelve aforementioned, this is a design flaw.  Databases are just that, information stores, they should not require any "special" logic to access them outside of whatever view structure is exposed.  Further, if the data needs to be manipulated in a **non-set** manner than you need to put it inside your application.  That is don't make your perform calculations when they can be offset to your application.

When you design your application you must ensure that you are not morphing your database to ignore the relational model.  In my experience this is one of the best ways to make your application unmanageable and slow.  To clarify, business logic **should not** live in the database, this makes it **hard** for others to use your data.  The typical argument against this is, "I am the only one using the data", to which I say that is an awful design reason.

Moving on, you should try to determine what actually works in the relational (set) model and build an application that can query that data.  Instead of building a database to fit your application.  That being said, `SOLID` **DOES NOT WORK WITH RELATIONAL MODELS AS THEY ARE NOT OBJECT ORIENTED**
    [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

> In computer programming, SOLID (Single responsibility, Open-closed,
>   Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency inversion)
>   is a mnemonic acronym introduced by Michael Feathers for the "first
>   five principles" identified by Robert C. Martin[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)[2] in the early
>   2000s[3] that stands for five basic principles of object-oriented
>   programming and design.

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

> The application links information from different systems and decides
>   when a group of records can be deleted (these are generic rules that
>   apply to all systems). There are then database specific rules that
>   must be applied before deleting. I was thinking about offsetting the
>   local business rules to stored procedures. –

Looking at this comment, I don't fully understand what database specific rules would be in place outside of auditing / soft deletes.  I would agree that **database specific** rules can be set to administrative stored procedures in the database, where you have to draw the line is when you get to issues such as the following:

My application queries against historic data unless it is older than `6 months` then it must be retrieved from offline storage.

The option you have for removing this data after `6 months`, is to allow the application to purge it via some business logic OR to create a scheduled task to do this cleanup as it is a normal database operation to remove tuples.

My argument here would be to place this in the database and to **disallow** your application from invoking these procedures.  In fact your application shouldn't even know a database exists, in a correctly abstracted application.  So if this is the example you are proposing then my solution would be as follows:

```
1) Create stored procedures in the database that only a maintenance based user can invoke,   NOT THE APPLICATION  
2) Create a database scheduled task to run these based on your data needs.
```

Comment: Thanks +1. The external databases contain information that has to be updated and sometimes deleted. The rules are different for each database. The application is there for search purposes and holds its own info in a database. Does this change your mind?

Comment: @w0051977 when you say updated/deleted can you clarify?  Do you mean in your application or in the external side?  Also, how does the application know what to search for?

Comment: The application links information from different systems and decides when a group of records can be deleted (these are generic rules that apply to all systems). There are then database specific rules that must be applied before deleting. I was thinking about offsetting the local business rules to stored procedures.

Comment: @w0051977 there I provided some more detail, let me know if this has confounded the issue or helps to clarify.

Comment: BUsiness logic must live in the database if there are many ways data can get into the database. MAny things like imports and reporting can;t bnecessarily go through the application and many systems have multiple applications accessing them and some busimness rules need to be enforced everywhere or you will have data integriuty problem. Things like FKs and constraints on columns all need to be in the database. Thinking that databases are only a data store is flawed thinking and generally results in bad data.

Comment: I do agree with you that object oriented design prionciples like SOLID have no palce in a relational database.

Comment: @HLGEM You are absolutely right. Some business rules need database-specific logic. Reports (aggregate, etc) and master data-speific fields (active / exists) usually is faster when queried inside database, especially when doing bulk processing (> 100 records).

Comment: On a side note, for achieving such SOLID state principle in domain layer, currently many developer tend to abstract the data access layer, resulting persistence ignorance at domain model.

Comment: @HLGEM IF you read what I stated there is a clear line to be drawn where logic resides.

Comment: I di read what you said and I disagree with it. AS a database sepcialist, it is this attitude that creates manyu of teh problems I am asked to fix. Any rule that must allpy to all data must be inteh database. Anyone who thinks the application is enough is short-sighted.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, thanks.  Are you able to look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699880/storing-tsql-in-a-database.  It is kind of linked to this one.

Comment: @w0051977 sure I can look at it in a bit

Comment: @HLGEM do you have any recommendations for design principles that fit the use-cases you mentioned (reporting\imports) and can help in maintainable such SQL code? maybe some recommended reading?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the notion of not putting business logic into SQL as well the concept of SQL being a set based language.

Think of SOLID as an OO specific implementation of some really good programming practices and apply them to any code you write, including SQL.  Good table schema design will incorporate SOLID ideas.

I have spent too much of my life debugging large complex stored procedures so if you can avoid it, please do.  If you must write stored procedure code then SOLID can help you.

For example I have a **large Stored Procedure which queries against a few dozen tables and it returns a data set for use by the printer to send 'welcome letters'**.  That is a classic example of a business process disguised as a ‘report’ and written in SQL.

### Looking at this operation from a SOLID lens:

#### It should have a Single responsibility and a Single reason to change.

The code both determines who gets a letter as well as what data goes into that letter.  If either aspect of the process changes you have to update and retest the entire system.  A solid principle would be to have a function that determines who gets a letter and what is in it.

This could be as simple as having a single query which will return a list of customers.  Feed that as an array of IDs or TVP into another stored procedure to collect data.

#### Open / Closed

In most SP (Stored Procedure) code the entire procedure is either hard coded or ‘data driven’.  Data driven is a usually a SQL effort against this principle.  The SQL flow is modified by a CASE pivoting off a field value or SQL in text fields that gets EVAL’d.

A SOLID approach to my problem can be seen in the ‘master’ SP that we just created  Now I have a SP that calls **GET_CUSTOMERS** and another that calls **GET_DATA**.  This *master* basically controls the workflow and that workflow should not change. The master is closed for modification.

If we then need to enhance the system to send emails, and emails have different data fields then I can swap out the call to **GET_DATA** with a call to **GET_DATA_FOR_EMAIL**.  *Open for modification*.

The master has a single responsibility. If the workflow changes, then this master changes, as per rule #1.

#### Liskov substitution principle

This is very OO, but to make a point let’s say that the **GET_CUSTOMERS** SP can been seen as a replaceable object here.  I should be able a different lookup, say **GET_CUSTOMERS_WHO_NEED_DIFFERENT_LETTER** and be able to reuse my code.  Or maybe **GET_CUSTOMERS_FOR_INTERNAL_TEST**?  If all the components of your system as one –off and not reusable then the system will be harder to maintain and understand.  This one may be a stretch.  Think less about OO object inheritance and more about functions with similar arguments that can be reused.

### Dependency inversion principle

This is the biggest FAIL I’ve seen.  Don’t write the code around selects and where clauses.  Where my system started with a *SELECT * FROM table, table, table where customers.letter-sent=false* (actually over 1k lines) I will hopefully end with *Find all customers and send them a letter*.  Start with the abstractions and code to where the highest level controls the workflow in the SP.

The idea is that the abstraction is 'find customers' and that returns a list of customers.  I should be able to swap that logic for something else in the code.  A violation of this which I often see is to have a 'find customers' that writes to a table joined on the customers table, and then another SP that reads that table.  In that case your abstraction leaked into the implementation and you went from reusable code to a system that sends letters for a specific table.

SQL is very powerful and it is way too easy to combine steps that should be separate in the abstraction to be comingled in the implementation.

Stored Procedures are a good tool that helps team exchange readability for performance and brings convenience at the expense of scalability.  It is still code and stealing patterns from other languages will only help if your overall design.

Very often you don't need a design pattern if your needs a simple.  If your code is more then 50 lines or so try to move it out to an app layer and / or think about a solid re-factoring.