# Storing TSQL in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Is it a bad idea to put TSQL in a database? For example, please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbSystems (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, Description VARCHAR(100), SQL (10000))
INSERT INTO dbSystems ('Sales System', 'DECLARE SalesVariable int..............")
INSERT INTO dbSystems ('Finance System', 'DECLARE FinanceVariable int..............")
INSERT INTO dbSystems ('Production System', 'DECLARE ProductionVariable int..............")
```

A VB.NET app would then be able to choose the SQL to run at runtime.

Alternatively, in the SQL field I could contain the name of a stored procedure and the VB.NET app could execute the stored procedure instead.

Comment: Didn't FoxPro have this sort of logic? However, stored procedures are exactly for this situation, just way more convenient and organized.

Comment: what will be the benefit of doing so? you will loose all the benifits of stored procedures by doing this

Comment: @ppeterka, thanks.  I could create a stored procedure but it seems to be a bit of an overkill as the logic is quite simple.  Do you still think the stored procedure route is more appropriate?

Comment: "the SQL field I could contain..." - what does this extra level of indirection (the VB app presumably has to have e.g. `Sales System` hard coded to know what row to locate) offer over simply having the VB app know which stored procedure to execute?

Comment: Use stored procedures.  They offer a lot of advantages in terms of security, maintainability, automatic dependency checking, compiled execution plans, passing variables, and probably a bunch of other things.

Comment: Stored procedures would be the way to go. They are compiled, syntax checked, and are quite convenient. I would totally go with them. Also, if there is a syntax error in the plain SQL-text field, you won't notice it until it gets to run probably 2 months later from the accidental modification. A SP is syntax checked, and is safe from this aspect...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the VB app connects to about two dozen databases.  That is why the extra layer of indirection is necessary in my opinion.

Comment: It still feels like this is just a re-building of the stored procedure system though - there's no inherent road-block to stored procedures accessing other databases than the one that they're contained within.

Comment: I have a general app with some standard reports.  Have some customers that want some specialized reports that I use this approach.

Comment: @Blam, do you store the stored procedure in a database or is it just the TSQL?.

Comment: Little of both but still something I try and avoid.

Comment: @Blam, can I ask why? Do you dislike sql?

Comment: No I am good at SQL and TSQL.  I consider putting TSQL statements in a table a hack that has a place but still something to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I use this tactic too in some projects.
If users cannot change the SQL syntax in the database, I don't see much of an security issue.
If they do you have to evaluate the SQL before using it.

Also if just some parameters in the query are different for the different row, you can just store those and run them in a stored procedure, or create dynamic SQL from the values.

I have used this for collecting and transferring data to another data format. The source data was stored in very different data formats and database designs. The target format was always the same EAV model.

I used the stored SQL as a part of the entire SQL statement that transfers the data of one batch of one day data.

Since I did not want a clutter of stored procedures that would increase in amount over time I chose this option.

Also I wanted to store a history of the SQL statements used per batch of data, for future reference when I changed the SQL statements in the future.

The option of using SP would still be viable, all though I don't know a way right now to store the history of SQL statements used over time.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on when you used this idea? +1.

Answer (score 1):

It's such a good idea that Microsoft already implemented it for you, as stored procedures. Take a look at [`sys.all_sql_modules`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184389.aspx):

```
object_id   
int     
ID of the object of the containing object. Is unique within a database.

definition  
nvarchar(max)   
SQL text that defines this module.
```

All that your application needs to supply is the name of the stored procedure to execute, and SQL Server will look up that SQL and execute it.

Comment: Except it's not compiled when stored as tsql in a varchar(max) column. It might be fine for small sets of data, but might not perform well otherwise.

Comment: @mrtig - there used to be a difference in the performance between ad-hoc SQL and stored procedures back in, I think it was, the 6.5 or 7 timeframe. It's not been true since at least the 2000 version of the product - both are subject to the same sets of optimizations.

Comment: @mrtig - and you may have missed the point that I was actually advocating the use of stored procedures - by pointing out that "storing T-SQL in the database" is what the stored procedure system is effectively doing (by showing the object catalog view that has columns analogous to the OPs suggested table)

Comment: How about this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/13/sql-server-stored-procedures-advantages-and-best-advantage/

Comment: @mrtig - If the assertion is that execution plans for ad-hoc SQL cannot be reused, which seems to be the assertion from the blog post, can you explain why the [product documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx) explains the circumstances under which ad-hoc plans are removed from the procedure cache?

Comment: This deals with memory pressure and ad-hoc executions. "Execution plans remain in the procedure cache as long as there is enough memory to store them." Does this prove equality in performance between sp_execsql '' and exec <some proc>?

Comment: @mrtig - yes, it does, because why would it *store* such execution plans if it didn't have a way to reuse them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37052/discussion-between-mrtig-and-damien-the-unbeliever)